# How to do a filter of this type: more ads by this user

Tags: drupal

Hi if someone could help me with this I would appreciate a lot, I doing a classified website running now in a local server while I am doing it and I want to do something like show more ads for this user

I ll explain better I want that in each Ad on my Web to display a block or link to all the Ads created for the user of the Ad that I am currently reading, If someone could help me I would appreciate a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the Views module. Create a view listing what you need. Then you can ad contextual filters depending on your needs.